# tourist visa for Australia, health assesment, how long until accepted?

Tags: australia, tourist-visas

I'm in Bali right now and applied for a tourist visa for Australia as my working holiday visa finished a few days ago.
Following the application they asked me for an health assesment which I concluded two days ago.
I haven't heard anything since and the problem is that i was supposed to fly out tonight.
I assume that I have to stay a few more days in Bali now.

My questions is, was anyone ever in a similar situation and knows how long it will take for the visa to be processed?
(I had stuff booked for my road trip in Australia that I might have to cancel..)

Answer (score 3):

Although I dislike being the bearer of bad news, the Department of Home Affairs website states:

> [It can take several weeks to assess your health. We might ask you to
>   have more health examinations depending on our assessment.
>
> You might avoid delay by completing your health examinations before
>   you apply for a visa through My Health Declarations (MHD).][1](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/help-support/meeting-our-requirements/health/when-to-have-health-examinations)

Whilst you might be lucky and get a particularly quick assessment, my experience with passport and visas here suggest you may need to wait for a little while yet.

The process is explained [here](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/help-support/meeting-our-requirements/health/after-your-health-examinations).